# General Exception when setting InlinePicture width

Tags: typescript, ms-word, office-js

**Context**

Currently, I am developing a Word add-in that uses the new Javascript API for Office. The add-in consists of some basic functionalities and a number of templates. The templates are coupled with an automatically opening task pane, in which the user can configure the template and fill out the required information. Within this task pane the user can change the image in the header. The user is asked to select an image from a set of predefined images, which are then placed in a content control.

**The Problem**

The placement of the images works correctly, however, I receive a `GeneralException` whenever I try to set the width of the image. Strangely enough, it does work in some instances (usually the first 1 to 3 times I adjust it). From my previous experience, I know the `GeneralException` can be caused if the content control is locked. However, this does not seem to be the case here. I have tried the following, in order to make it work.

- Add a paragraph and add the picture in there, rather than adding it directly to the content control.
- Removed the editing protection altogether.
- Tried different widths.
- Adjusting the picture width after a context sync.

**The Code**

The line `'picture.width = 71;` causes the error in question.

```
// Needed to interact with Word in typescript.
declare const Word: any;

export interface IImage {
  imageId: string;
  base64String: string;
}

export function InsertImageInControl(imageId: string, controlTitle: string) {
  Word.run(function(context) {
    // Retrieves content control.
    var contentControl = context.document.contentControls
      .getByTitle(controlTitle)
      .getFirst();

    // Disable editing protection.
    contentControl.cannotEdit = false;

    return context
      .sync()
      .then(function() {
        FetchBase64Image(imageId)
          .then(function(image) {
            let picture = contentControl.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(
              image.base64String,
              "Replace"
            );

            // Line that causes the error:
            picture.width = 71;

            // Reenable editing protection.
            contentControl.cannotEdit = true;
          })
          .then(context.sync)
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
}

export function FetchBase64Image(imageId: string): Promise<IImage> {
  return new Promise<IImage>(function(resolve, reject) {
    fetch("api/Images/" + imageId)
      .then(function(response) {
        resolve(response.json() as Promise<IImage>);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for this question. I was playing a bit with this and a few comments.

1. Not sure if you are aware of this but we provide a TypeScript library as well for Office.js and no need to create your own.
2. I created a sample basically replicating your code. You can try my snippet by using [Script Lab](http://aka.ms/scriptlab)  . Please [import this yaml](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/99527196f527cfe500aa426adff43a1e)  there and run the code. **IMPORTANT**: make sure to add a content control in the header with the "image" title to replicate this. then click the insert Picture button, and then many times the change width button.

I was able to get an exception a few times, but only when I was trying really quickly to set the image width. I think that what's going on its a race condition and you are trying to change the width in the content control who is read only. This should be for a very brief period of time (milliseconds?), and you can retry the operation and it should work.

Please give it a try !

Btw with our TS library you can greatly  simplify your code and can look like this:

```js
async function changeWidth() {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        //unlock cc
        context.document.contentControls.getByTitle("image").getFirst().cannotEdit = false;

        await context.sync();

        //set image within cc width...
        context.document.contentControls.getByTitle("image").getFirst().inlinePictures.getFirst().width = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 50);;
    
        await context.sync();

        //lock cc
        context.document.contentControls.getByTitle("image").getFirst().cannotEdit = true;
        
        await context.sync();
        console.log("success!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Juan! Unfortunately, I keep getting the error even if I retry. I think Ill try to solve it in another way for now.

Comment: in what build are you observing this?

Comment: Version 1803, Build 9126.2152